# TSQL Intelligence Search, Type Conversion Error, SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, search

I am trying to write the single search statement to search the Product Views in multiple ways.  My requirements are as follow:

1. If @SearchType is not provided, show all products
2. If @SearchType is **ProductID** (Integer), search by ProductID
3. If @SearchType is **Code** (VARCHAR(50)), search by Code

Here is my TSQL script.  It works fine if I used, the ProductID which is Integer.

```
DECLARE @SearchType VARCHAR(20) = 'Code'
DECLARE @Value1 VARCHAR(50) = 'XYZ123'

SELECT
    *
FROM
    dbo.vProductsCurrent
WHERE
    (@SearchType IS NULL 
        OR (@SearchType = 'ProductID' AND ProductID = @Value1 )
        OR (@SearchType = 'Code' AND Code = @Value1 )           
        )
```

But when I changed it to search by **Code**, I got the Conversion Failed Error.  I don't understand why it is executing ProductID check even though @SearchType is **Code**.  AFAIK, if the first condition returns false, it doesn't evaluate the remaining part of the query in "AND" conditions.

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'XYZ123' to data type int.
```

So, I forced the ProductID to convert to Varchar(10) before doing the search

```
OR (@SearchType = 'ProductID' AND CAST(ProductID AS VARCHAR(10)) = @Value1 )
```

Since the data type of the ProductID is changed, the Indexing benefit of the ProductID no longer exists.

Is there any better way to do that?

PS.  I don't want to use multiple If / Else ....  Actually my query has about 10 possible search conditions, and not only ProductID and Code.  I removed those for the question.

Comment: You can't tell SQL Server to evaluate the conditions in any specific order - assume they will all be evaluated. The way to get around this is to use a `CASE` expression. Or, better yet, instead of using a single variable to pass strings that are actually different data types, pass 10 different parameters. The ones that are NULL will simply be ignored: problem solved.

Comment: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) by Erland Sommarskog should get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass all parameters with corresponding type or null if not needed.

```
DECLARE @Value1 INT = 11
DECLARE @Value2 VARCHAR(50) = 'XYZ123'
DECLARE @Value3 DATETIME = '20140505'

SELECT
    *
FROM
    dbo.vProductsCurrent
WHERE
    (  ProductID = @Value1 OR @Value1 IS NULL)
     AND (Code = @Value2 OR @Value2 IS NULL )   
     AND (DateFrom >= @Value3 OR @Value3 IS NULL )
     -- AND ...
```

Inspired in previous comment from @Aaron Bertrand

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use dynamic SQL queries, for dynamically constructing your query based on your condition.

```
Eg:

DECLARE @SelectStatement NVARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @WhereClause NVARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @FullStatement NVARCHAR(4000);


SET @SelectStatement = 'SELECT * FROM TableName'

IF (cond1 is true)
    SET @WhereClause = '@SearchType = ''ProductID'' AND ProductID = @Value1';
ELSE
    SET @WhereClause = '@SearchType = ''Code'' AND Code = @Value1';

SET @FullStatement = @SelectStatement + ISNULL(@WhereClause,'')

PRINT @FullStatement

EXECUTE sp_executesql @FullStatement
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL is set based, there is not a flow in the execution of the queries, if not the one based on the level of subqueries and for recursive `CTE`.

That said it's possible create the check you want

```
DECLARE @SearchType VARCHAR(20) = 'Code'
DECLARE @Value1 VARCHAR(50) = 'XYZ123'

SELECT
    *
FROM
    dbo.vProductsCurrent
WHERE (@Value1 = CASE WHEN @SearchType = 'ProductID' THEN ProductID
                      WHEN @SearchType = 'Code' THEN Code
                      ELSE @Value1
                 END)
   OR @SearchType IS NULL
```

The `CASE` check the search type to decide against which field verify the parameter, the `ELSE` is a fallback in case `@SearchType` is `NULL` .

Comment: Nice one. But isnt it quite dirty in a data type conversion way? I mean, varchar comparing with int or varchar depends on condition. Some casting would make it neater, right?

Answer (score 0):

Using `CASE` is the most flexible solution for 'select' statement. For unused condition, 'column=column' will be evaluated which is always 'true'.

```
DECLARE @SearchType VARCHAR(20) = 'Code'
DECLARE @Value1 VARCHAR(50) = 'XYZ123'

SELECT
    *
FROM
    dbo.vProductsCurrent
WHERE 
   ProductID = 
      case WHEN @SearchType = 'ProductID' 
        then cast( @Value1 as integer) 
        else ProductID 
        end 
   and
   Code = 
      case WHEN @SearchType = 'Code' 
        then cast( @Value1 as varchar(50) )
        else Code 
        end
```